# Azurepipeline runtime paramter for the ARM template Json file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there any option to have the Azurepipeline runtime parameter to pass the ARM templates object properties. For example i need to pass the ARM template "dimension" values to the ARM template using the Azurepipeline dynamically. So since its a runtime paramster users can add the dimensions accordingly with their requirements.

Below is the parameter "dimension" which i want to pass to the azure runtime parameter and in backend this should work in the ARM template

```
                        "dimensions": [
                            {
                                "name": "DatabaseName",
                                "operator": "Include",
                                "values": [
                                    "mydb"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "StatusCode",
                                "operator": "Include",
                                "values": [
                                    "429"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
```

Below is the ARM template part where I am trying to pass the above paramater values

```
            "evaluationFrequency": "[parameters('evaluationFrequency')]",
            "windowSize": "[parameters('windowSize')]",                
            "criteria": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]",
                        "name": "Metric1",
                        "metricNamespace": "[parameters('metricNamespace')]",
                        "metricName": "[parameters('metricName')]",
                        "dimensions": "[parameters('dimensions')]",
                        "operator": "[parameters('operator')]",
                        "timeAggregation": "[parameters('timeAggregation')]",
                        "criterionType": "[parameters('criterionType')]"
                    }
                ],
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked many document from Microsoft but didn't found any way that passes the Azure Pipeline runtime parameter to the ARM templates object properties.

If you want integrate Azure Resource Manager templates (ARM templates) with Azure Pipelines for continuous integration and continuous deployment use the [ARM template deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) to **pass azure pipelines variables to ARM templates**.

Create a variable group that store values and secrets that you might want to be passed into a YAML pipeline or make available across multiple pipelines, then try using **overrideParameters** parameter for the task to override your ARM template's parameters with the variables defined in your variable group as shown below.

```yaml
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
   displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
   inputs:
     azureResourceManagerConnection: <connection>
     ...
     overrideParameters: -storageAcctName azurerg -Username $(vmusername)
     ...
     ...
```

I would suggest to read this [Integrate ARM templates with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines) document from Microsoft for more information.

Comment: Yes.. OverrideParamaters option there. But I am not sure how to pass this list(object) type for dimensions values to the arm template in my scenario. Already tried multiple ways and resulted with json validation error,